# how can i list all internet dns records associated with a specific ip address?

Tags: domain-name-system

think my brain's gone to sleep! thankyou...

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

If they don't have reverse dns pointing to them then you can't.  It is a one way lookup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single database with all DNS records. There are several tools out of here (mostly not free) which shows a list of domains associated with an IP address.

One of them is [whois.domaintools.com](http://whois.domaintools.com). Stackoverflow.com has IP-address 64.34.119.12.

http://whois.domaintools.com/64.34.119.12 gives:

> Reverse IP:   31 websites use this
>   address. (examples:
>   advertisingoverflow.com askubuntu.com
>   basicallymoney.com bschoolanswer.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Robtex](http://www.robtex.com/) is a pretty good site for that but you cannot have any guarantee another dns server dosen't have a different record for it.

Any DNS server can have a record for a zone even if it has no authority on it, the "small" drawback is, only clients of this DNS server will get this particular record, no replication will occur outside this particular authority.